# Remove OS from Linux Dual-Boot

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, multi-boot, jolicloud

I'm currently dual-booting two Linux-based operating systems on my laptop, Jolicloud and Ubuntu 10.10. How do I remove Jolicloud completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically all you have to do is

1. Backup to at least 7 1/2 armored and padlocked locations around the world, in at least 6 different continents and pray to the unicorns that your data loves you.
2. Boot into Ubuntu and run `gparted` and delete the Jolicloud partition.
3. Apply changes.
4. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Which sounds way too easy. But should work.

Comment: Try [rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and use `gpartd` to delete the partition and re-create it as something else.